# How to program a Koolertron macropad?

Tags: keyboard, xinput, xbindkeys

I bought [this macropad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076LRJ528) awhile ago but I haven't been able to figure out how to program it. Right now it types keys like a normal keyboard but I want to beable to run commands when I press the buttons. What would be the best way to make that happen?

Edit: forgot to mention that I'm using Manjaro

Comment: From the last line of "About this item"(amazon page): Tips: User can download the keyboard configuration software from URL on user manual. Compatible with Windows 7,8,10, Mac OS, Linux. (Windows XP incompatibled) If you can't find the software download link, please feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally figured it out. Then answer id [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd). This program remaps keys and can do it on a per-keyboard-basis. I struggled with keyd for abit because I couldn't get commands to work.

So heres a tutorial on how to bind Koolertron Macropad keys to commands.

## 1. Install keyd

Click [here](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd#installation) for instructions

## 2. Add environment variables to the keyd systemd service

Run `env` to get a list of your environment variables. In systemd you can add as many `Environment=` values to a service. Edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/keyd.service` and add `Environment=` lines for each variable you got from the `env` command

## 3. Enable systemd service

`sudo systemctl enable --now keyd.service`

Atleast that's how I got it to work

Edit: forgot to append my screenfetch

```
 dan@workstation
 OS: Manjaro 23.0.3 Uranos
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.133-1-MANJARO
 Uptime: 24m
 Packages: 2302
 Shell: zsh 5.9
 Resolution: 5760x1080
 DE: GNOME
 WM: i3
 GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Adwaita
 Font: Cantarell 11
 Disk: 374G / 1.9T (22%)
 CPU: Intel Core i9-10850K @ 20x 5.2GHz [45.0°C]
 GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
 RAM: 4711MiB / 64205MiB
```